# jquery.cycle.all.js not working with Meteor (using coffeescript and scss)

Tags: jquery, html, meteor, coffeescript, sass

I'm currently trying to get the following fiddle working in Meteor using coffeescript: https://jsfiddle.net/jdcast/60r2uxdk/

I have made sure that jquery.cycle.all.js is in my /client/external/ dir.
I have three simple files to hold what you see in the fiddle: temp.html, temp.coffee and temp.scss.  temp.html and temp.scss hold exactly what's in the fiddle.  In temp.coffee I have tried:

```
Template.temp.rendered = ->
       $('#site').cycle
         fx: 'scrollHorz'
         next: '.next a'
         prev: '.prev a'
         startingSlide: 1
         timeout: 0
       return
```

I have also tried:

```
Template.temp.created = ->
       $('#site').cycle
         fx: 'scrollHorz'
         next: '.next a'
         prev: '.prev a'
         startingSlide: 1
         timeout: 0
       return
```

and I've tried this:

```
Meteor.startup ->
       $('#site').cycle
         fx: 'scrollHorz'
         next: '.next a'
         prev: '.prev a'
         startingSlide: 1
         timeout: 0
       return
```

The first two approaches exhibit zero response.  The last one I get the following messages in the js console:

```
[cycle] DOM not ready, queuing slideshow 
[cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector
```

My questions are:
1) What am I doing wrong?

2)How do I best go about porting the example in that jsfiddle to a Meteor app (written in coffeescript and scss)?